# Can you restore a table in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I dropped a mysql table and don't believe I explicitly enabled any sort of backups is there a way to undo the drop statement?

Answer (score 0):

Once a table is dropped, it is gone. Without a backup you won't get it back. So, no there's no way to undo the drop statement.

Answer (score 0):

Closest I got was to partially restore the structure (with no data) by retracing the create/alter statements. I went to help > locate log files and analyzed the log file for a given DB.

[image]

P.S: Problem is that for reasons unknown when you alter the table via "alter" button in workbench it doesn't register the queries in log files, it just says "Altered changes" or something which is pretty dumb, otherwise the whole structure would have been restored...